# datagridview upper left cell select all loads all - how to prevent?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

When I select the upper left corner of the datagridview to select all records it bogs down (freezes until it loads and then unlocks).  I'm assuming this happens because it's trying to reload the grid...though I'm not exactly sure this is what's happening.  The table has 10,000 records.

Anyway, I'm trying to prevent the freeze from happening.

I found the following to capture the event (clicking the upper left cell).

**Having captured this how do I halt the reloading or whatever's causing it to freeze and eventually unlock?**

```
 Private Sub DataGridView1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) _
    Handles DataGridView1.CellMouseDown
    If e.RowIndex = -1 And e.ColumnIndex = -1 Then
        m_MouseDownFromdgv = True
        OnMouseDown(e)
    End If
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseDown(ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
    If m_MouseDownFromdgv Then
        m_MouseDownFromdgv = False
        MyBase.OnMouseDown(e)
    End If
End Sub
```

thanks,
Jim

Comment: Loading 10k rows wont do it, thats not really that many rows. More likely *how* they are loaded/reloaded, though nothing related to that is shown in the question.

Comment: One thing to check is if there is a loop within a loop when loading, I have come across this before resulting in checking 10,000 records becoming 100,000,000 (if each of the 10,000 checks another 10,000).

Comment: That was it.  As I have several datagridview events firing when cells are entered and exited, many of the events have loops and such.  I fixed the issue by adding a gate keeper on the front of each event routine using

  `If Not DataGridView1.AreAllCellsSelected(True) Then event routine.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OSKM offered the idea that upon selecting the upper left corner box that the slow down may be the result of falling into a loop.

I discovered this was the case.

As I have several datagridview events firing when cells are entered and exited, many of the events have loops and such. I fixed the issue by adding a gate keeper on the front of each event routine using
 `If Not DataGridView1.AreAllCellsSelected(True) Then event routine`
.